# SQL Server Maintenance plan history check status

Tags: sql, sql-server, prtg

I need to monitor the maintenance plan if still running, I've found an old post ( thanks to Don [SQL Server Maintenance plan history check for success or failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33858357/sql-server-maintenance-plan-history-check-for-success-or-failure/63033611?noredirect=1#comment111466668_63033611) ) to query the log and get the jobs result, but this give only the result after finish:

```
SELECT
    mp.name AS [MTX Plan Name],
    msp.subplan_name AS [Sub Plan Name],    
    mpl.start_time AS [JobStart],
    mpl.end_time AS [JobEnd],
    mpl.succeeded AS [JobSucceeded]
FROM
    msdb.dbo.sysmaintplan_plans mp
    INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysmaintplan_subplans msp ON mp.id = msp.plan_id
    INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysmaintplan_log mpl ON msp.subplan_id = mpl.subplan_id
        AND mpl.task_detail_id = -- Get the most recent run for this database
            (SELECT TOP 1 ld.task_detail_id 
            FROM msdb.dbo.sysmaintplan_logdetail ld
            WHERE ld.command LIKE ('%['+db_name()+']%')
            ORDER BY ld.start_time DESC)
```

Comment: In sql-agent jobs, if check the specific task history, it will show you current unfinished jobs if there was.

Comment: I know, but I need that query to automatically chek by a monitoring tool, in my case PRTG.

Answer (score 1):

This query will give you active/running jobs which are related to Maintenance plans. Whatever is there means it is running now

```
SELECT sj.name
   , sja.*
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity AS sja
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs AS sj ON sja.job_id = sj.job_id
WHERE sja.start_execution_date IS NOT NULL
   AND sja.stop_execution_date IS NULL
   AND sja.job_id IN (SELECT job_id FROM msdb.dbo.sysmaintplan_subplans)
```

Let me know if you need help with integration to PRTG

Comment: Thank you jana! Now I use your query to check if something maintenance plan still running and the first query to check if the last job complete successfully. I need two PRTG sensor, but isn't a problem! Thank you again